# Rewrite SQL query to Fix Functional Dependency Issue Caused By MySQL 5.7 Strict Mode

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, mysql-5.7, mysql-error-1055

I recently upgraded my MySQL server to version 5.7 and the following example query does not work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT * 
        FROM exam_results 
        WHERE exam_body_id = 6674 
        AND exam_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
        AND subject_ids LIKE '%4674%' 
        ORDER BY score DESC 
    ) AS top_scores 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY percent_score DESC, time_advantage DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

The query is supposed to select exam results from the specified table matching the top scorers who wrote a particular exam within some time interval. The reason why I had to include a GROUP BY clause when I first wrote the query was to eliminate duplicate users, i.e. users who have more than one top score from writing the exam within the same time period. Without eliminating duplicate user IDs, a query for the top 10 high scorers could return exam results from the same person.

My question is: how do I rewrite this query to remove the error associated with MySQL 5.7 strict mode enforced on GROUP BY clauses while still retaining the functionality I want?

Comment: It's good it doesn't work anymore, since it was silently producing unpredictable results.

Comment: What are some unpredictable results that you anticipate would occur if it worked?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because you never really wanted aggregation to begin with.  So, you used a MySQL extension that allowed your syntax -- even though it is wrong by the definition of SQL:  The `GROUP BY` and `SELECT` clauses are incompatible.

You appear to want the row with the maximum score for each user meeting the filtering conditions.  A much better approach is to use window functions:

```
SELECT er.* 
FROM (SELECT er.*,
             ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC) as seqnum
      FROM exam_results er 
      WHERE exam_body_id = 6674 AND
            exam_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND
            subject_ids LIKE '%4674%' 
    ) er
WHERE seqnum = 1
ORDER BY percent_score DESC, time_advantage DESC 
LIMIT 10;
```

You can do something similar in older versions of MySQL.  Probably the closest method uses variables:

```
SELECT er.*,
       (@rn := if(@u = user_id, @rn + 1,
                  if(@u := user_id, 1, 1)
                 )
       ) as rn
FROM (SELECT er.*
      FROM exam_results 
      WHERE exam_body_id = 6674 AND
            exam_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND
            subject_ids LIKE '%4674%' 
      ORDER BY user_id, score DESC
     ) er CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT @u := -1, @rn := 0) params
HAVING rn = 1
ORDER BY percent_score DESC, time_advantage DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: thanks for your answer. You're right about what I'm trying to accomplish. I indeed want the row with the maximum score for each user meeting the filtering conditions. The only challenge I'm having is that MySQL returns error  #1064 indicating an error in the SQL syntax, and recommending that I check the manual that corresponds to my MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY score DESC).

Comment: The Impaler points out that your query only works in MySQL 8+ and my brief research shows that prior to MySQL 8.0, I can't use window functions like ROW_NUMBER. I'm currently trying to see if there's a way to rewrite this to work on MySQL 5.7 without having to upgrade yet again to MySQL 8.

Comment: Thanks for the edit showing an alternative for older versions using user-defined variables.

Comment: A similar query that I ended up using which gave me the behavior I wanted was:
`SELECT * FROM (SELECT *, @row_number := CASE WHEN @user_id <> er.user_id THEN 1 ELSE @row_number + 1 END AS row_number, @user_id := er.user_id FROM exam_results er CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @user_id := null) params WHERE exam_body_id = 6674 AND exam_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND subject_ids LIKE '%4674%' ORDER BY er.user_id, score DESC) inner_er HAVING inner_er.row_number = 1 ORDER BY score DESC, percent_score DESC, time_advantage DESC LIMIT 10`

Comment: @danmaze . . . Assigning variables in one expression and using them in another is simply not guaranteed to work in MySQL.  There is a reason the code is written using a single expression for the variables.

Comment: Just recently upgraded to a CentOS 7 server with more RAM and was able to upgrade the MySQL server from 5.7 to 8. Your initial query has come in really handy and works much more reliably. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

When you aggregate (`GROUP BY`) a result set by a subset of the columns (`user_id`), then all the other columns need to be aggregated.

Note: according to the SQL Standard if you are grouping by the primary key this is not necessary, since all the other columns are dependent on the PK. Nevertheless, this is not the case in your question.

Now, you can use any aggregation function like `MAX()`, `MIN()`, `SUM()`, etc. I chose to use `MAX()`, but you can change it for any of them.

The query can run as:

```
SELECT 
  user_id,
  max(exam_body_id),
  max(exam_date),
  max(subject_ids),
  max(percent_score),
  max(time_advantage)
FROM exam_results 
WHERE exam_body_id = 6674 
  AND exam_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) 
  AND subject_ids LIKE '%4674%' 
GROUP BY user_id 
ORDER BY max(percent_score) DESC, max(time_advantage) DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

See running example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/m7872WLLohxQQaMtyzSVXV/0).

Now, why do you need to aggregate the other columns, you ask? Since you are gruping rows the engine needs to produce a single row per group. Therefore, you need to tell the engine which value to pick when there are many values to pick from: the biggest one, the smallest one, the average of them, etc.

In MySQL 5.7.4 or older, the engine didn't require you to aggregate the other columns. The engine silently and **randomly** decided for you. You may have got the result you wanted today, but tomorrow the engine could choose the `MIN()` instead of the `MAX()` without you knowing, therefore leading to unpredictable results every time you run the query.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I remember reading about specifying aggregate functions for other columns as a solution when I first encountered this issue. Your query works perfectly. However, the only challenge I still have is that I would like to also select the `exam_id` column for the top score so that I can use that to retrieve all of the other needed information about that exam. Using an aggregate function on that column will guarantee wrong results. Any suggestions or recommendations?

Comment: @danmaze If you want all the information for a particular row of a group, then that's not aggregation, but "filtering" instead. Gordon's answer resolves that requirement (though his query works in MySQL 8+).

Comment: I see. You're right about Gordon's answer. It doesn't work on MySQL 5.7.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to Gordon's answer using user-defined variables and a CASE conditional statement for older versions of MySQL is as follows:

```
SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
            @row_number := CASE WHEN @user_id <> er.user_id 
                                THEN 1 
                                ELSE @row_number + 1 END 
                           AS row_number,
            @user_id := er.user_id
        FROM exam_results er
        CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_number := 0, @user_id := null) params
            WHERE exam_body_id = 6674 AND
            exam_date >= DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK) AND
            subject_ids LIKE '%4674%' 
        ORDER BY er.user_id, score DESC
    ) inner_er
HAVING inner_er.row_number = 1
ORDER BY score DESC, percent_score DESC, time_advantage DESC 
LIMIT 10
```

This achieved the filtering behavior I wanted without having to rely on the unpredictable behavior of a GROUP BY clause and aggregate functions.

Comment: Assigning variables in one expression and using them in another is simply not guaranteed to work in MySQL.  Use a single expression for the variables if you want to be sure that the code really does what you expect.  In addition, in some more recent (but older) versions of MySQL, the `order by` needs to be a subquery if used with variables.  I recommend you stick with the version in my answer.

Comment: I now see the issue you're referring to in my query. I'll go with your recommendation. Thank you.